# Missing formal parameter on setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-places-api, settimeout

I'm currently writing a script in google apps script to get a list of stores in a specific location that meet my text search.  I'm trying to set a timeout function for when I'm trying to receive the next page of results from google places api, and for some reason it keeps telling me that `error: setTimeout function is missing a formal parameter`.  I've looked at everything online and the way I have it in my code looks like all the other ways to execute that function.  If anyone could help me out that would be great! Thanks!

Here is my *setTimeout function*

```
        function setTimeout( function(){
          while(tempPage != null){

            count = count++;
            var nxtUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken=" + tempPage + "&location=41.661129,-91.530167&radius=8050&key=" + apiKey;
            var tempResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(nxtUrl);
            var tempJson = tempResponse.getContentText();
            Logger.log(tempResponse);

            tempPage = JSON.parse(tempJson).next_page_token;

            Logger.log("Page count: " + count);

            for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++){

              var tempPlace = JSON.parse(tempJson).results[j];

              Logger.log("Name: " + tempPlace.name);
              Logger.log("Address: " + tempPlace.formatted_address);
            }// end for loop

          }// end while loop
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: Remove the very first `function` from that snippet. It's just `setTimeout(...);`

Comment: I get a new error that says setTimout is not defined

Comment: It's possible you can't use it. I'm not sure why you're using it anyway

Comment: you have to have a delay between requesting multiple pages through google places api, or else it will return an INVALID_REQUEST error.  So I figured that I could just use setTimout to add a delay between requests.

Comment: Ok, but your code doesn't work like that. You have a while loop in the callback, so your code in theory waits for three seconds, then runs the while loop without any pause in between requests. But if you can't use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, that issue is moot anyway.

Comment: I solved it.  You are correct.  setTimout cannot be used in google apps script.  I had to use Utilities.sleep() instead.

Comment: SetTimeout is clientside and Google Apps Script runs on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Google apps script does not use the setTimeout function.  The solution is to use Utilities.sleep() function instead.

```
        Utilities.sleep(3000);

          while(tempPage != null){

            count = count++;
            var nxtUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken=" + tempPage + "&location=41.661129,-91.530167&radius=8050&key=" + apiKey;
            var tempResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(nxtUrl);
            var tempJson = tempResponse.getContentText();
            Logger.log(tempResponse);

            tempPage = JSON.parse(tempJson).next_page_token;

            Logger.log("Page count: " + count);

            for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++){

              var tempPlace = JSON.parse(tempJson).results[j];

              Logger.log("Name: " + tempPlace.name);
              Logger.log("Address: " + tempPlace.formatted_address);
            }// end for loop

          }// end while loop
```

Comment: How does Utilities.sleep() replace setTimeout()?

Comment: Surely there must be an asynchronous way of doing this?